# SQL code logic for reiteration in update statement

Tags: sql, while-loop, sql-server-2012

Given : I have a table with 3 column namely ID,MARKS and subject.

For example -

Table name (**Marks**)

```
 ID       Marks  Subject  
323232    20  
323232    10  
323232    25  
323232     2
```

For subject column, we are asked to update from the below table

Table name (**Subject**)

```
 ID      Subject  
323232    ENG  
323232    SCI  
323232    MAT
```

In this case, we need to update the subject column of Subject as below:

```
 ID      Marks  Subject  
323232    20    ENG  
323232    10    SCI  
323232    25    MAT  
323232    2     ENG       --- ONCE THE 3 DISTINCT VALUES ARE UPDATED WE MUST REPEAT UNTIL THE ID CHANGES.
```

I have tried to update using while loop logic, but after updating the MAT values i can't be go back to ENG.

let me know if this is attainable using SQL queries. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Also, are you really running both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012?  If not, please fix the tags. Oh and, formatting.

Comment: So, you don't care which mark gets updated with which subject?, doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: you can update using cursor, but  honestly its strange, how you will know that the mark 25 is for MAT and not ENG, which criteria was used to sort the entries in this way?

Comment: Your design is bad. The subject table should not have the same id for every subject.  Nor should you repeat subject in two tables.  You should a have a subject table with a unique SubjectId for every subject (never name things ID that is a SQL antipattern) You should have a person table with a unique PersonID. Then you should have a Marks table with PersonID, SubjectId and Mark.

Comment: You certainly would not need to resort to a cursor for this. But without some better details about the logic behind how the update should be applied it is impossible to answer this.

Comment: Yes. though its logically incorrect. but i need like that only.

Comment: @HadiHassan, it is best to not recommend a cursor as a starting place. 99% of them are not needed and only people who are very senior DBAs should ever need to write one.

Comment: I got dizzy just from looking at those 3s and 2s. This is cruel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would *want* to, but you can do this with modulus arithmetic:

```
with toupdate as (
      select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from marks m
     ),
     t as (
      select s.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from subject s
     )
update toupdate
    from toupdate join
         s
         on toupdate.id = s.id and toupdate.seqnum % s.cnt = s.seqnum % s.cnt;
```

Comment: can you explain what is "with toupdate" means in the first line?

Comment: @JohnChristopher . . . That is a called a common table expression, usually referred to by the acronym CTE.